# Atmega 32, Program to drive motor , How to take input integer from user

Tags: embedded, atmega

I am trying to write a simple program to take input from user by hterm, when User enters "motor" & "25" the motor will rotate in 25 clockwise and 25 anticlockwise direction

```
    //Define clock-speed and include necessary headers
    #define F_CPU 1000000
    #include <avr/io.h>
    #include <util/delay.h>
    #include <inttypes.h>
    #include <avr/io.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <avr/interrupt.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdint.h>
    #include <util/delay.h>
    #include <ctype.h>

    #define F_CPU 16000000UL
    #define BAUD 9600UL

    char cmd[40];

    void uart_init(void)                            // initializing UART
    {
        UBRRH = 0;
        UBRRL = ((F_CPU+BAUD*8)/(BAUD*16)-1);

        UCSRC |= 0x86;                              // 8N1 Data
        UCSRB  = 0x18;                              // Receiving and Transmitting
    }

    int uart_putch(char ch, FILE *stream)           // Function for sending Data to PC
    {
        if (ch == '\n')
        uart_putch('\r', stream);
        while (!(UCSRA & (1<<UDRE)));
        UDR=ch;
        return 0;
    }

    int uart_getch(FILE *stream)                    // Function for receiving Data from PC
    {
        unsigned char ch;   while (!(UCSRA & (1<<RXC)));
        ch=UDR;

        uart_putch(ch,stream);                      // Echo the output back to the terminal

        return (tolower(ch));

    }

    FILE uart_str = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(uart_putch, uart_getch, _FDEV_SETUP_RW);  // Important, not deleting

    void loeschen()                     // Delete the String
    {
        int strnglen = 0;
        while (strnglen < 41 && cmd[strnglen] != 0)
        {
            cmd[strnglen]= 0;
            strnglen++;
        }
    }

    // Define the stepping angle
    // Note: Divide by 2 if you are doing half-stepping. for filter test 1.8 defult
    #define MIN_STEP 1.8

    /* Define an array containing values to be sent at the required Port - for Full-stepping

      <first four bits> - <last four bits> = <decimal equivalent>

       00000001 = 1 ; 01000000 = 4
       00000100 = 4 ; 00010000 = 16
       00000010 = 2 ; 00001000 = 8
       00001000 = 8 ; 00100000 = 32
    */
    unsigned short control_array_full[4] = {4,16,8,32};

    /* Define an array containing values to be sent at the required Port - for Half-stepping

    <first four bits> - <last four bits> = <decimal equivalent>

    0000-1001 = 8 + 1 = 9  ; 0010-0100 = 32 + 4 =36
    0000-0001 = 1     ;      0000-0100 = 4
    0000-0101 = 4 + 1 = 5 ;  00010100 = 16 + 4 = 20
    00000100 = 4        ;   00010000  = 16

    00000110 = 4 + 2 = 6  ; 00011000  = 16+8=24
    0000-0010 =          ;  00-001000 = 8
    0000-1010 = 8 + 2 = 10  ; 00-101000 = 40
    0000-1000 = 8            ; 00-100000 = 32
    */
    unsigned short control_array_half[8] = {36,4,20,16,24,8,40,32};


    // Adjust this delay to control effective RPM
    // Do not make it very small as rotor will not be able to move so fast
    // Currently set at 100ms
    void delay()
    {
    _delay_ms(100);
    }

    void move_clockwise(unsigned short revolutions){
      int i=0;
      for (i=0; i < (revolutions* 360 /MIN_STEP) ; i++)

      {

      //Note: Take modulo (%) with 8 when half-stepping and change array too
      PORTD = control_array_half[i % 4];
      delay();
     }

    }

    void move_anticlockwise(unsigned short revolutions){
     int i;
      for (i = (revolutions* 360 /MIN_STEP); i > 0 ; i--){

      //Note: Take modulo (%) with 8 when half-stepping and change array too
      PORTD = control_array_half[i % 4];
      delay();
     }
    }

    int main()
    {

     // Enter infinte loop
     // Make changes here to suit your requirements

     uart_init();                   // initializing UART

     stdout = stdin = &uart_str;        // Necessary to compare whole Strings

      while(1){


          scanf("%s",&cmd);         // Read String from Data Register
    printf ("Please enter number of motor rotation for clockwise and anticlockwise");
          items_read = scanf ("%d", &numbers[i]); // Read integer for motor revolution


          if(strcmp(cmd, "motor") == 0)
          {
              DDRD = 0b00111110; //Set PORTD  4 bits for output
       //Enter number of revolutions required in brackets
            move_clockwise(items_read);

            move_anticlockwise(items_read);
          }   
      DDRD = 0b00000000;
  }
        loeschen();
}
```

Now, The problem is that when I will delete these lines from main()

```
  items_read = scanf ("%d", &numbers[i]);
  scanf ("%d",&i);
```

& make items_read in `move_clockwise(items_read);` as:

```
move_clockwise(25);
move_anticlockwise(25);
```

Then when user enters "motor" then motor is running `move_clockwise(25);` but `move_anticlockwise(25);` is not running, what I would like is to take both "motor", number for clockwise and number for anticlockwise....

I would really appreciate if anyone can help me with this!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some parts of your program such as for collecting the strings seem to be missing.  But maybe you should first make an even simpler test case and strip out everything but the two move commands.  What happens if you issue them in the other order, anticlockwise first, or call by itself?  Or you could make a preliminary test program which advances once step upon receipt of each serial character.

Comment: I tried to use only scanf and printf, scanf is working but neither printf or puts is working for me!!, Could any one tell me what am I doing wrong here I want an int also from user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in my opinion you're only clearing "cmd" in loeschen(), but you never assining any value.
Second "cmd" is NOT any type of UART dataregister.

DDRD is DataDirectionRegister D, that means you can set some pin to input or output mode.
Use PORTD to set a pin high or low, in example `PORTD |= 1<<PD0;` to set Port D Pin 0 to high.

I guess you prefer german documentation, because you named one function "loeschen()" ;-), so why don't you visit [mikrocontroller.net AVR GCC Tutorial (UART)](http://www.mikrocontroller.net/articles/AVR-GCC-Tutorial/Der_UART/)?

If you like more technic detailed youtube-stuff, et voila: [Introduction to UART](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8uEKWpVf10&list=PLE72E4CFE73BD1DE1&index=45)

RXT (ATMEGA16) - for example:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Definitions
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#define BAUD 9600UL                             
#define UBRR_VAL ((F_CPU+BAUD*8)/(BAUD*16)-1)   
#define BAUD_REAL (F_CPU/(16*(UBRR_VAL+1)))     
#define BAUD_ERROR ((BAUD_REAL*1000)/BAUD)      

#if ((BAUD_ERROR<990) || (BAUD_ERROR>1010))
#error Baud to high
#endif

#define UART_MAX_STRING_LENGHT 20               // Max lenght


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// UART-Receive-Variables
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
volatile uint8_t uart_str_complete = 0;                         // FLAG - String received
volatile uint8_t uart_str_count = 0;                            // Current position
volatile char uart_string[UART_MAX_STRING_LENGHT + 1] = "";     // received string


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// ISR-UART 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
ISR(USART_RXC_vect)
{
    unsigned char nextChar;
    nextChar = UDR;         // read data from buffer

    if(uart_str_complete == 0)  // UART-String is currently usen
    {
        if(nextChar != '\n' && nextChar != '\r' && uart_str_count < UART_MAX_STRING_LENGHT)
        {
            uart_string[uart_str_count] = nextChar; 
            uart_str_count++;                       
        }
        else
        {
            uart_string[uart_str_count] = '\0'; 
            uart_str_count = 0;                 
            uart_str_complete = 1;
        }
    }
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Init UART
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void Init_UART_Async()
{
    UBRRH = UBRR_VAL >> 8;
    UBRRL = UBRR_VAL & 0xFF;

    UCSRB |= (1<<TXEN);                         // UART TX high
    UCSRB |= (1<<RXEN);                         // UART RX high
    UCSRB |= (1<<RXCIE);                        // UART RX Interrupt enable
    UCSRC = (1<<URSEL)|(1<<UCSZ1)|(1<<UCSZ0);   // Asynchron 8N1

    sei();                                      // Enable interrups
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Main
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(void)
{

    Init_UART_Async();

    while(1)
    {       
        HandleCommunication();      // <-- Handle your communication ;-)

        // and to some other cool stuff here
    }
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Handle Communication
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void HandleCommunication()
{
    if(uart_str_complete == 1)
    {
        strcpy(received_string, uart_string);   // copy received string
        strcpy(uart_string, "");                // empty uart-string
        uart_str_complete = 0;                  // set flag to 0

        // handle your communication
    }
}
```

After understanding how UART is working, you should check your codeparts
like "scanf("%s",&cmd);" in an console-application - that's easier to find some errors.

I hope this helps you a little, but I guess the best solution is when you're knowing what you're doing.

-Crazy

Comment: Thanks it really helped, and I found that my `uart_init()` was not functioning properly, So I also corrected it                    
`void USARTInit(uint16_t ubrr_value)
{
 UBRRL = ubrr_value;
 UBRRH = (ubrr_value>>8);
 UCSRC=(1<<URSEL)|(3<<UCSZ0);
 UCSRB=(1<<RXEN)|(1<<TXEN);
}` also I checked my connection of Atmega32 when I am connecting txd to txd of serial port and rxd of atmega32 to rxd of serial port it is working properly now. And, I was thinking wasn't it suppose to be in inverse order!!